# How to find what is on a diagonal of a list (Snake game with diagonal moves)

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
[[1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]]
```

- If I want go to `top-right` from `9` which is `matrix[0][8]`, it should return `27` or `matrix[2][6]`
- If I go to the `bottom-right` corner from `30`, I should get `8` or `matrix[0][7]`
- `11` to `top-left` -> `22`
- `20` to right `11`

I am trying to implement spherical 2d matrix, so that wherever you go, you will end up in the same position, like in the game snake, but with diagonal moves too.
How can I do this in Python?

It can be solved by parsing down, but there should be some formula using which I can say what is located where.
[image]

Comment: can you show the code ([mcve]) of what you have tried?

Comment: Use increasing/decreasing offsets from the initial index position, or define all possible combinations of valid index positions and then sum them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Create function, in which you can pass matrix, row number and column

Answer (score 1):

For a circular wrap around, when one coordinate goes out of bound, the other one needs to be set back by the least of the two dimensions.  This is relatively easy to figure out when the diagonal increases in both direction but would be trickier when going backward.  So, an easy way to look at this would be to recurse with inverted coordinates and invert the result when displacements (directions) contain a negative increment.   This allows you to only think of the positive increment logic:

```
def nextPos(r,c,dr,dc,board):
    rows, cols = len(board),len(board[0])
    if dr < 0 or dc < 0:
        r = rows-1-r if dr<0 else r              # invert row going up
        c = cols-1-c if dc<0 else c              # invert column going left
        r,c = nextPos(r,c,abs(dr),abs(dc),board) # down/right movement
        r = rows-1-r if dr<0 else r              # un-invert row
        c = cols-1-c if dc<0 else c              # un-invert column
        return r,c
    r,c = r+dr, c+dc        # dc and dr are only 1 or 0
    if r >= rows and dc:    # diagonal out of bound (rows) 
        # c -= min(cols,r)  # with horizontal wrap - not what OP wanted
        r,c = (r,c - min(cols,r)) if c>=rows else (rows-c,0)  
    elif c >= cols and dr:  # diagonal out of bound (columns)
        # r -= min(rows,c)  # with horizontal wrap - not what OP wanted
        r,c = (r - min(rows,c),c) if r>=cols else (0,cols-r)
    return  r%rows,c%cols    # wrap around
```

Testing all directions from various starting points:

```
board = [[1,  2,  3,  4,   5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
         [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
         [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]]

directions = {"left":(0,-1), "right":(0,1), "up":(-1,0), "down":(1,0),
              "upLeft":(-1,-1), "upRight":(-1,1),
              "downLeft":(1,-1),"downRight":(1,1)}

for start in [(0,0),(0,1),(1,9),(2,2)]:
    for dirName,(dr,dc) in directions.items():
        r,c = start
        print(start,dirName,":",board[r][c],end="")
        while True:
            r,c = nextPos(r,c,dr,dc,board)
            print(" ->",board[r][c],end="")
            if (r,c) == start: break
        print()
```

output:

```
(0, 0) left : 1 -> 10 -> 9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
(0, 0) right : 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 1
(0, 0) up : 1 -> 21 -> 11 -> 1
(0, 0) down : 1 -> 11 -> 21 -> 1
(0, 0) upLeft : 1 -> 23 -> 12 -> 1
(0, 0) upRight : 1 -> 1
(0, 0) downLeft : 1 -> 1
(0, 0) downRight : 1 -> 12 -> 23 -> 1
(0, 1) left : 2 -> 1 -> 10 -> 9 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2
(0, 1) right : 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 1 -> 2
(0, 1) up : 2 -> 22 -> 12 -> 2
(0, 1) down : 2 -> 12 -> 22 -> 2
(0, 1) upLeft : 2 -> 24 -> 13 -> 2
(0, 1) upRight : 2 -> 11 -> 2
(0, 1) downLeft : 2 -> 11 -> 2
(0, 1) downRight : 2 -> 13 -> 24 -> 2
(1, 9) left : 20 -> 19 -> 18 -> 17 -> 16 -> 15 -> 14 -> 13 -> 12 -> 11 -> 20
(1, 9) right : 20 -> 11 -> 12 -> 13 -> 14 -> 15 -> 16 -> 17 -> 18 -> 19 -> 20
(1, 9) up : 20 -> 10 -> 30 -> 20
(1, 9) down : 20 -> 30 -> 10 -> 20
(1, 9) upLeft : 20 -> 9 -> 20
(1, 9) upRight : 20 -> 29 -> 20
(1, 9) downLeft : 20 -> 29 -> 20
(1, 9) downRight : 20 -> 9 -> 20
(2, 2) left : 23 -> 22 -> 21 -> 30 -> 29 -> 28 -> 27 -> 26 -> 25 -> 24 -> 23
(2, 2) right : 23 -> 24 -> 25 -> 26 -> 27 -> 28 -> 29 -> 30 -> 21 -> 22 -> 23
(2, 2) up : 23 -> 13 -> 3 -> 23
(2, 2) down : 23 -> 3 -> 13 -> 23
(2, 2) upLeft : 23 -> 12 -> 1 -> 23
(2, 2) upRight : 23 -> 14 -> 5 -> 23
(2, 2) downLeft : 23 -> 5 -> 14 -> 23
(2, 2) downRight : 23 -> 1 -> 12 -> 23
```

Comment: But shouldn't
`print(nextPos(0, 1, -1, 1, board))` return (1,0), and it returns (2, 9)

Comment: An increment of (-1,1) moves up and to the right.  (1,0) would be down and to the left from (0,1).  The up-right diagonal from (0,1) is 2 -> 30 -> 11 -> 2 on the board

Comment: No, it should be 2 -> 11 -> 2

Comment: OK, so you don't want to wrap around horizontally.  You should have mentioned that in the question.  Positions near corners are edge cases that need special attention.  Those should be clearly defined in your question if you want answers to be relevant.

Comment: This would also mean that an increment of (-1,1) from position (0,0) would go back to (0,0) essentially preventing the snake from moving in that direction (or its opposite).

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to work like that

Comment: Adjusted answer to prevent horizontal wrap-around.  Hitting sides now produces a vertical reset and a reduced horizontal wrap (of same magnitude as vertical offset)..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are taking two steps in some cases and only one step in others, but here is a generic function that'll spit out the indices given a start, direction, and number of steps.

```
values = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
    [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
]

rows = len(values)
cols = len(values[0])


def get_index(start, direction, steps, rows = rows, cols = cols):
    a, b = start
    v0, v1 = direction
    
    c = a + v0*steps
    d = b + v1*steps
    
    return [c % rows, d % cols]

print(get_index([0,8], [1, -1], 2))
print(get_index([-1, -1], [-1, -1], 2))
print(get_index([1, 0], [1, 1], 1))
print(get_index([1, -1], [0, 1], 1))
```

Comment: It's always one step, it appears on the other side of the list, your code doesn't seem to be working correctly
print(get_index([0,8], [-1, 1], 1)) should return 27 not 30

Comment: I don't understand why it should go to 27. If I were to wrap around, the bottom row appears on top of the so it looks like `[28, 29, 30], [8, 9, 10]`. If I go up and to the right, should I not land at 30? Perhaps I've misunderstood how you are handling the wraparound.

Comment: It goes to top-right corner, not going top, and than right, please check the photo, that I have provided.

Comment: What happens if you start from 10 and go up?

Comment: You end up at 30

Comment: I see, the wraparound is dependent on the direction of travel, interesting...

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 10
y = 3
def move(a, b, i, j):
    if i*j == 0:
        return (a+i)%x, (b+j)%y
    c_len = cycle_len(a, b, i , j)
    ctx = cycle_trans_x(a, b, i, j)
    cty = cycle_trans_y(a, b, i, j)
    return ctx + ((a+i-ctx)%c_len), cty + ((b+j-cty)%c_len)

def cycle_trans_x(a, b, i, j):
    sign = 2*(i*j > 0) - 1
    return a - min(a, (y + sign*b - (sign<0))%y)

def cycle_trans_y(a, b, i, j):
    sign = 2*(i*j > 0) - 1
    return b - min(b, (x + sign*a - (sign<0))%x)

def cycle_len(a, b, i, j):
    if i*j > 0:
        return min(a, b) + min(x-a, y-b)
    else:
        return min(a, y-b-1) + min(x-a, b+1)

print(move(8, 0, 1, -1), (6, 2))
print(move(9, 2, 1, 1), (7, 0))
print(move(0, 1, -1, -1), (1, 2))
print(move(9, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1))
```